# How does docker clean up expired images and containers generated by deployment

Tags: docker

When I modify my code and submit it to gitlab, Jenkins will start to build my new code and package the new image, but it will not delete the old image and container, so there are many expired images and containers in docker. These images and containers are generated during my development. I don't need to keep them. How should I delete them correctly.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb7rY.png)

[container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f6do.png)

Comment: Sorry, I updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check docker resource usage

```
docker system df
```

To clean all un-used images, all stopped containers, all networks not used by at least one container, all dangling images, all dangling build cache

```
docker system prune
```

You can also clean individual resource

```
docker <container|volume|image|network> prune
```